# Error when I try to compile the kernel 2.6.37

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have downloaded the kernel 2.6.37 from kernel.org.
I have tried to compile it but I get an error:

```
$ make menuconfig
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
***
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'. Stop.
```

I have copied the actual kernel configuration to `.config`:

```
cp /boot/config-2.6.37-20110117 .config
```

I have executed `make menuconfig` another time but it compiles the full kernel without showing a menu. o_O
I have compiled this kernel a few days without problems.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: So so that it's mentioned here, and it has nothing to do with compiling the Kernel, there's a [Mainline Kernel PPA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) which does already contain 2.6.37. These are already compiled binary packages that you can just install. They come with all of the same caveats as compiling the kernel yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was an alias of `make` that I have defined in my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

I do this on a fairly regular basis. It's quite simple. I follow the ["Old fashioned way" instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile). If you're not, read that from the beginning and make sure you have the right things installed. My steps are as follows:

1. Download kernel, extract it, and cd into the resultant directory.
2. Copy in the config from the running kernel:

   ```
   cp -vi /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
   ```
3. Show the new config keys and set values (optional):

   ```
   make oldconfig
   ```
4. Main config (if I need to change things, optional again):

   ```
   make menuconfig
   ```
5. Compile and package:

   ```
   env CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=8 fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd kernel-image kernel-headers
   ```

Comment: The solution was so simply.
I had defined one alias to "make" that interfered.