# 2.6.37 (or 2.6.36) Ubuntu Kernel in Maverick. Is this possible and where can I get it?

Tags: kernel, ppa

Is it possible to get a newer kernel with the ubuntu patches applied (as a deb + related packages - such as headers, since this machine would be best not compiling the kernel for time restraints)? I'd prefer a ppa, if one exists.

Comment: @Jorge The edit may be incorrect if Roland wants Ubuntu-specific patchsets applied rather than just rocking a vanilla kernel. Hard to tell. I'll leave Roland to roll it back if that's what he really meant.

Comment: yes, I am looking for the ubuntu specific patchsets, as I have tried doing otherwise before and was bitten a few times :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a PPA for mainline kernel builds.  You can read all about it [on the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

The easiest way to get a more recent kernel is to grab the appropriate deb for your hardware [from launchpad](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and install it.

Comment: these do not contain the ubuntu patches.

Comment: I give up trying to find a ppa with the patches, I'll stick with what I have till I can fix my screen.

Answer (score 2):

I build my own kernels. Following the "old fashioned way" from the Ubuntu help page makes it a doddle. Most of the time is spent waiting for it to compile (it's big -- 6GB over 80,000 files once compiled). Don't be scared by that. It's a good learning experience.

Other people may suggest "mainline" builds but these are only kept up to date for the latest version of Ubuntu. You *can* usually just pull these back but pair that with GCC version mismatches and other undesirable things, it's usually just easier to compile it yourself.

I've gone over the steps at least five times on here already, so [here's a link to my last effort](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22267/error-when-i-try-to-compile-the-kernel-2-6-37/22270#22270).

Comment: I would really prefer not to use this method. I build normal software all the time, but for several reasons including what I mentioned in my question I would like to avoid doing this with my kernel until I have another system that I can play around with.

Comment: In fairness "getting bitten" doesn't really apply to kernels because you can (and will) have several versions installed alongside each other. If one doesn't work for you, you can just choose an older one in grub at boot. But in terms of getting Ubuntu "specific" patches, you either do it yourself or find somebody making custom kernels (there are several projects and individuals doing this).

Comment: My laptop screen is broken, that is why I can't really change kernels on boot so easily :/. Of course I still like to be on the cutting edge and to be able to test new features etc in various parts of the OS etc... So, yeah, I would prefer something that is less likely to cause problems (that would be tricky to fix)