# Compile new kernel for ubuntu 11.10

Tags: power-management

My laptop is hp dv6 6080 with sandy bridge cpu.
Linux has power issue and use more battery but i see in sites that new kernel doesn't has this problem. Is this true?
if i compile this kernel for ubuntu 11.10 can i solve this problem?
i use techniques for decreasing battery use in linux but linux use many battery as windows use low than Linux!
how can i solve this problem in linux?

Comment: What kernel do you need to install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably look at pre-built versions of the Kernel before jumping into compiling your own. The [Mainline Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) should be your first port of call. Pick a version, install the package and reboot. If it works: awesome. If everything explodes, just select an older version from Grub and remove the package once you're booted up.

If you do want to follow the dark path of compiling your own kernel, I've written a few answers over the years that might help point you in the right direction.

- [Building own kernel on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30456/building-own-kernel-on-ubuntu/30475#30475)
- [Error when I try to compile the kernel 2.6.37](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22267/error-when-i-try-to-compile-the-kernel-2-6-37/22270#22270)
- [Correct way to apply patches to your kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11249/correct-way-to-apply-patches-to-your-kernel/11254#11254)
- [2.6.37 (or 2.6.36) Ubuntu Kernel in Maverick. Is this possible and where can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23276/2-6-37-or-2-6-36-ubuntu-kernel-in-maverick-is-this-possible-and-where-can-i-g/23279#23279)

They're old posts but everything in them should still apply today.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just try to install a new kernel with apt-get?
Try
`apt-cache search linux-image`
in order to find a new kernel package. Install it with
`apt-get install <package name>`
afterwards and reboot.

If you are not logged in as root, you should place a "sudo" in front of every command listed here.
Is this information useful for you?

Comment: This will not get you a "newer" kernel, just the latest version for in the currently selected repository. Ubuntu doesn't tend to push major Kernel updates to old versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for you to install a mainline kernel from here:

[How can I install a newer kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100233/how-can-i-install-a-newer-kernel)

Your best option may be to install 12.04. Be warned it is in beta at the moment, you might want to wait for the release.